# how to remove indentation from <pre> tag

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to place a text in

```
 <pre></pre>
```

tags to keep text formatting. Everything is working fine but I cannot remove the first line indent. How to change this code to remove the first line indent

```
    @foreach (var m in Model.postModelList)
{
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-vertical">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.PostDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => m.PostTitle )
        </dd>

        <dd><pre>
            @Html.ActionLink(m.PostContent, "DisplayFullPost","Post", new {Id = m.PostId }, null )
        </pre></dd>
    </dl>

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
<dd><pre>@Html.ActionLink(m.PostContent, "DisplayFullPost","Post", new {Id = m.PostId }, null )</pre></dd>
```

It's taking the newline and indentation from the source literally.